# Passing variables into other methods

Tags: android

I have a method that starts an if statement onClick to show a question from a list array, remove that item, and then increment an int in order to show another question onClick again. The variable is defined prior to the onCreate. When I click the button the first time a random item is pulled from the array and displayed. If I click it again it does nothing. Anything?

Java

```
public class Careunderfirequiz extends AppCompatActivity{

int questionsAnswered = 0;

List<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
    questions.add("1");
    questions.add("2");
    questions.add("3");
    questions.add("4");
    questions.add("5");
    questions.add("6");
    questions.add("7");
    questions.add("8");
    questions.add("9");
    questions.add("10");
}

public void nextQuestion(View view){
    TextView questionsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questions);
    Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    if(questionsAnswered == 0){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        String randQuestion = questions.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(questions.size()));
        questionsTextView.setText(randQuestion);
        questions.remove(randQuestion);
        questionsAnswered++;
    }
    if(questionsAnswered == 1){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        String randQuestion = questions.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(questions.size()));
        questionsTextView.setText(randQuestion);
        questions.remove(randQuestion);
        questionsAnswered++;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The `if (questionAnwerered == 0)` and `if (questionAnswered == 1)` don't seem necessary, as your code is always the same anyway.  Just watch out for questionAnswered == 10, as there are only 10 questions. Also the `next` variable is not used and it wouldn't be necessary to find it anyway, as the button is passed to the method as the `view` variable anyways (assuming you set `android:onclick="nextQuestion"` for the button in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You used `remove` method with `String` input, and this will remove the item using value not index, if `Random` class selected for example value=2 two times, in first time `remove` method will remove item with `value =2` , but in second time `remove` method does nothing, because item with `value=2` is already removed.

please fix the `nextQuestion` method

```
   public void nextQuestion(View view){
        TextView questionsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questions);
        Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        if(questionsAnswered == 0 || questionsAnswered ==1){
            int index=randomGenerator.nextInt(questions.size())
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            String randQuestion = questions.get(index);
            questionsTextView.setText(randQuestion);
            questions.remove(index);
            questionsAnswered++;
        }


    }
```